Are there efficient algorithms for the chinese remainder theorem mod p?
Setup:
Suppose you are given a non-negative integer $n$ which has bounds $ 0 \le n \le B$  and  you know the values of
$$ n  \mod q_i $$
For a sequence of natural numbers $q_0 ... q_r$  s.t. $\text{LCM}(q_0, ... q_r) > B$
Then the Chinese Remainder Theorem allows you to find $n$ using an algorithm that is quadratic in the number digits of $n$   via Bezout's Identity.
One can then consider this as an algorithmic problem. The problem is as follows:
Problem: Given a collection of moduli $q_i$ and values of $n \mod q_i$ as well as the upperbound $B$ how do you efficiently find the smallest $n$ obeying those congruences that is $\le B$?
Solution: The CRT with Bezouts algorithm gives us an algorithm quadratic in the number of digits in $n$.
I am interested in a variation of this problem.
Question:
I am curious if given the same information, how to compute $n \mod p$  for a $p$ that is coprime to all the $q_0 ... q_r$ with runtime faster than the quadratic time of the original problem.
Some Ideas:
Now of course there is a naïve approach of just finding $n$, and then computing $n \mod p$ but this is too slow. I believe there should exist FASTER approaches that allow us to skip the intermediate step of finding $n$. What would be an example of such an algorithm?

Not sure what you mean.  Since $L=\text {LCM} ({q_i})$ is prime to $p$ and the integer solution is only defined up to a multiple of $L$, you can get any residue class $\pmod p$.  Equivalently, for any residue class $r\pmod p$ you could add a new congruence to the CRT problem, namely $n\equiv r\pmod p$, and we'd still have a solution.

Are you possible asking for the residue $\pmod p$ of the least positive integer solution?  If so, I suspect there's nothing to be done that's better than solving over $\mathbb Z$ and reducing.  That "least" isn't really a property that you can detect $\pmod p$.

@lulu yes the value $\mod p$ of the least integer solution. It's size is possibly MUCH smaller than $n$ so one would hope there exist algorithms with running times much smaller than quadratic in the digits of $n$. (Ideally just polynomial in the number of digits of $y$)

I suggest editing your post to reflect that...nothing in what you wrote suggests that this is what you meant, I just guessed at it.   Again, though, my guess would be that there's nothing better than solving and reducing.  "least" isn't really a good modular concept.

Thanks for pointing that out. I have refactored the question a bit, I think it still could be a lot more clear but hopefully this is better. Let me know if the intent is more obvious now/are there any specific parts you feel are still problematic.
